# Is this MySQL change set xml format?

Tags: mysql

I was not able to verify whether this file (for DB changes) is somehow supported by MySQL JDBC driver

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<change-set release="3.0">

    <change number="1">
        <description>
            Create Version Table.
        </description>
        <sql separator=";">
            CREATE TABLE DB_VERSION (
                RELEASE_NAME  VARCHAR(255) BINARY NOT NULL,
                VER           NUMERIC DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
            );
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql separator=";"><![CDATA[
                -- drop table DB_VERSION;
            ]]></sql>
        </rollback>
    </change>
</change-set>
```

I got it from vendor saying it is standard MySQL. I have no idea how to execute the same (for testing purposes), I mean whole file using some interface. More I'm interested whether there is some tool helping me generate it (in opposite, me creating it manually)...

I tried google returning some Liguibase results (?!?), there are no namespaces, so I do not know what to try next...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is, but the create statement in question is indeed valid MySQL syntax and the table creates fine.. I executed it by copying what's in `<sql></sql>` element.

Comment: *I was not able to verify* Why not? Copy the part between `<sql>` and `</sql>` out and execute it. Does it result in a table named `DB_VERSION` that has those two columns? If so, you've verified it.

Comment: I somehow want to run whole file, not statement by statement... This is small example, in real file I have several hundreds of statements... I modified the question to make it easier to understand...

Comment: Why are you not asking the vendor who supplied you with the file these questions?

Comment: I asked them and they said what I wrote above, but as I'm not so familiar with MySQL and I didn't find it using Google I'm asking here first...